# How to make authenticated Firestore queries when handling a webhook in a firebase function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My app receives a webhook from a 3rd party service, telling it that data is ready to be queried.

The webhook payload includes:

- `UserId`
- `ObjectId` of the object whose data is ready.

In order to query the data, I need to get an access token:

```
const { accessToken } = await db
    .collection('users').doc(userId)
    .collection('objects').doc(objectId)
    .get();

// then I can:
fetchUpdatedData(objectId, accessToken)
```

However, I have rules in place to require that users' data may only be accessed by the user:

```
# `firestore.rules`
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Reject by default
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }

    // Users can edit their own document
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    // Users can manage their subcollections
    match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

What's the typical way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use security rules to limit queries coming from backends like Cloud Functions that use any of the server SDKs.  **Server SDKs initialize with a service account, which always bypass security rules.**  You're going to have to duplicate the relevant checks from the rules in your backend code to check if the query should be done on behalf of the user.